# Putting OGP tags, it occurs 'The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.'

Tags: html, facebook

I'm putting some OGP tags on my website below.
http://en.come-to.tokyo/

Every time I check on Facebook Debugger here, same error come up.
"The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

Though og:type is there, how can I do for it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your HTML errors, the following lines include a semicolon that should not be there:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://en.come-to.tokyo"; />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://en.come-to.tokyo/images/logo-movie-bg.png"; />
```

Correct:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://en.come-to.tokyo" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://en.come-to.tokyo/images/logo-movie-bg.png" />
```

You should also consider using a larger image for `og:image`, check out the docs for the specifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to fix as you show me. But it doesn't work.
And replaced the image. I'd appreciate if you could give some another advice.
http://en.come-to.tokyo/

Comment: And I'm using Facebook debugger below.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
It says I still have the error 'The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.'.

Comment: you still got the semicolon in the image tag

Comment: Sorry, I missed something wrong. Just fix it.
But still appear the error on the debugger. What's wrong?

Comment: a lot of things can be the issue then. for example, there is a whitespace in the og prefix, there is lots of useless line breaks, there is "Description" instead of "description", ...

Comment: Thanks for checking my html. I fixed some issues. But message is still there. Any idea?